# Replacing big img onclick other img JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a script in JS that changes the big image to the src of the image you click on. I currently have this and the img tag does change, but weirdly the innerHTML just adds the code underneath the old img tag.

So if I view the inspector after clicking an img, I have the old img tag and I can click that one open, where my new img tag is. I thought innerHTML should replace the whole content of the class?

The reason I'm using innerHTML instead of setattribute is so I could still use the srcset functionalities for responsive.

This is what I receive in my inspector:

```
<img
 class="product__img__accessory" srcset="
          ./assets/detail/mini_leeslicht_big.jpg  384w,
          ./assets/detail/mini_leeslicht_big@1.5x.jpg  576w,
          ./assets/detail/mini_leeslicht_big@2x.jpg  768w
            " sizes="25vw" src="./assets/detail/mini_leeslicht_big.jpg" alt="Mini Boekenlicht">
<img class="product__img__accessory" srcset="
      ./assets/detail/mini_leeslicht2_big.jpg 384w,
      ./assets/detail/mini_leeslicht2_big@1.5x.jpg 576w,
      ./assets/detail/mini_leeslicht2_big@2x.jpg 768w
    " sizes="25vw" src="./assets/detail/mini_leeslicht2_big.jpg" alt="ddd">
</img>
```

My code:

```
<section class="product__img" id="product-image">
    <h2 class="product__title"><?php echo $accessory['name']?></h2>
    <img class="product__img__accessory"
          srcset="
          ./assets/detail/<?php echo $accessory['img_slug'] . '_big.jpg'?>  384w,
          ./assets/detail/<?php echo $accessory['img_slug'] . '_big@1.5x.jpg'?>  576w,
          ./assets/detail/<?php echo $accessory['img_slug'] . '_big@2x.jpg'?>  768w
            "
          sizes="25vw"
          src="./assets/detail/<?php echo $accessory['img_slug'] . '_big.jpg'?>"
          alt="<?php echo $accessory['name']?>"
          />
  </section>
```

```
  const handleClickLink = e => {
    // href naar link niet volgen
    e.preventDefault();

    // path naar afbeelding ophalen
    const $link = e.currentTarget;
    console.log($link);
    const src = $link.querySelector(`img`).getAttribute(`src`);
    const src2 = src.replace('_thumb', '_big');
    const newSrc = src2.substring(0, src2.lastIndexOf('.'));
    console.log(newSrc);
    // path van grote afbeelding overschrijven
    document.querySelector('.product__img__accessory').innerHTML =
    `<img class="product__img__accessory"
    srcset="
      ${newSrc}.jpg 384w,
      ${newSrc}@1.5x.jpg 576w,
      ${newSrc}@2x.jpg 768w
    "
    sizes="25vw"
    src="${newSrc}.jpg"
    alt="ddd"
    />`;

    // pushstate instellen voor correct url
    const path = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    const qs = $link.getAttribute(`href`).split('?')[1];
    window.history.pushState({}, '', `${path}?${qs}`);
  };
```

Comment: Sorry, I replaced it with text.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research I concluded that I could just as easily use SetAttribute with srcset, so this is my solution:

```
  const handleClickLink = e => {
    // href naar link niet volgen
    e.preventDefault();

    // path naar afbeelding ophalen
    const $link = e.currentTarget;
    console.log($link);
    const src = $link.querySelector(`img`).getAttribute(`src`);
    const src2 = src.replace('_thumb', '_big');
    const newSrc = src2.substring(0, src2.lastIndexOf('.'));
    console.log(newSrc);
    // path van grote afbeelding overschrijven
    const newSrcSet =
    `${newSrc}.jpg 384w,
    ${newSrc}@1.5x.jpg 576w,
    ${newSrc}@2x.jpg 768w`;

    const newSrcImg = `${newSrc}.jpg`;

    document.querySelector('#product-image img').setAttribute('srcset', newSrcSet);
    document.querySelector('#product-image img').setAttribute('src', newSrcImg);

    // pushstate instellen voor correct url
    const path = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    const qs = $link.getAttribute(`href`).split('?')[1];
    window.history.pushState({}, '', `${path}?${qs}`);
  };
```